Log Linearization for Interest Rate in Real Business Cycle (RBC) Model
Under the baseline real-business-cycle model specification in Romer's Advanced Macro, we are provided with the following formula for the real interest rate in period $t$:
$$r_{t}=\alpha\left(\frac{A_{t}L_{t}}{K_{t}}\right)^{1-\alpha}-\delta,$$
where $A_{t}$, $L_{t}$ and $K_{t}$ denotes technology, labor and capital, respectively, and $\delta$ is the fraction of capital that is depreciated each period.
For a simulation of the model's implications of a positive 1 percent technology shock, we assume that:

each period corresponds to a quarter, and take for baseline parameter values $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$, $g=0.5\%$, $n=0.25\%$, $\delta=2.5\%$, $\rho_{A}=0.95$, $\rho_{G}=0.95$, and $\bar{G}$, $\rho$, and $b$ such that $\left(\frac{G}{Y}\right)^{*}=0.2$, $r^{*}=1.5\%$ and $\ell^{*}=\frac{1}{3}$.

The results of the simulation then goes on to show that

The annual interest rate
increases by about one-seventh of a percentage point in the period of the
shock

I'm trying to obtain the last result (i.e., proving that the annual interest rate increases by approximately 14.29% from the shock), but this has proven difficult.
I understand that the strategy is to log-linearize the equation for the interest rate above and express it in terms of $\tilde{K}_{t}$, $\tilde{A}_{t}$ and $\tilde{G}_{t}$ (where a tilde denotes the difference between the log of the variance and the log of its balanced-growth path value). With the provided parameter values and assumption of positive one percent technology shock at time, capital is unchanged, labor increases by 0.35 percent, consumption increases by 0.38 percent and output increases by 0.9 percent, at the time of the shock.
Here's where I got so far. So the equation for the interest rate can be rewritten as
$$ 1+r_{t} = \frac{(1-\delta)K_{t} + \alpha Y_{t}}{K_{t}},$$
since $Y_{t}=K^{\alpha}\left(A_{t}L_{t}\right)^{1-\alpha}$. Taking natural logs of both sides yield
$$\ln (1+r_{t}) = \ln ((1-\delta)K_{t} + \alpha Y_{t}) - \ln (K_{t})$$
Subsequent attempts to log-linearize this equation was unsuccessful.
